# Динамическое создание конструктора

Tags: java

В Java программе необходимо создать объект, но заранее не известно сколько и какие поля будут участвовать в конструкторе. Есть ли возможность во время выполнения добавлять к классу конструктор с необходимым набором параметров?

Comment: Наверное вам стоит обратить внимание на шаблон builder

Comment: В конструкторе можете использовать `Object... args` и подставлять аргументы через Reflection, но мне кажется это очень плохая практика.

Comment: @user_Kyrt думаю, что лучше показать, как Вы собрались вызывать такой конструктор, а там будет понятно, как его реализовать.

Comment: @KoVadim прав - дополните вопрос кодом или примерами, иначе тяжело подсказать.

Comment: `@KoVadim` Как такового кода ещё нет. Создать и добавить конструктор в класс нагло, при помощи `RandomAccessFile` , но в таком случае, как его вызывать. Можно конечно перегрузить конструктор, но если полей будет 10+, то написание такого количества комбинаций конструктора может показаться несколько рутинной работой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой способ хакинга (заранее предупреждаю, что это **антипаттерн**):

1. Задаемся некой структурой данных описывающих поведение гипотетического  конструктора (в реалии конечно же класс с заданным конструктором) - нечто типа псевдоязыка - вполне сойдет какой-нибудь xml/json
2. Парсим псевдоязык и генерируем на лету исходник класса
3. Через [ToolProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) вызываем в рантайме компилятор Javа
4. Далее через [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) загружаем объектник класса
5. Далее уже все как обычно: у нас есть ссылка на класс, вызываем через рефлексию его конструктор.

Еще раз - так не рекомендуется делать, но иногда так делается. Сам лично когда то делал такую поделушку.

Answer (score 3):

Есть следующие классические пути.

В качестве примера используем такой **максимальный** конструктор

```
public Person(String name, Int age, Double weight)
```

Если вариантов использования конструктора ограниченное количество (т.е., например, всего три варианта: name+age,+weight, name+age, name+weight), то правильным путем будет создание трех конструкторов:

```
public Person(String name, Int age, Double weight){код}
public Person(String name, Int age){
    this(name, age, 25.4);
}
public Person(String name, Double weight){
    this(name, 78, weight);
}
```

Если прямо совсем неопределенное количество аргументов одного класса, то имеет смысл либо передавать их коллекцию:

```
public MyNumbers(List<Int> numbers){код}
```

Либо использовать конструкцию [VARARGS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public MyNumbers(Int... numbers){код}
```

В принципе никто не мешает передавать `List<Object>`, но это если совсем безнадёга - так делать не надо.

Если аргументы заранее известны, их много, но неизвестно, какие будут заданы, то стоит использовать шаблон проектирования [Builder](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Если **совсем упрощенно**, то:

```
class PersonBuilder{
    private String name = "";
    private Int age = 78;
    private Double weight = 25.4;

    public PersonBuilder setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    // для двух других параметров аналогично

    public Person build(){
        return new Person(name, age, weight);
    }
}

Person person = (PersonBuilder()).setName("John").setWeight(22.7).build();
```

Comment: .подойдёт, спс.

Answer (score 2):

**Нет.** В Java методы, к сожалению для многих, методы **не** являются обьектами, поэтому их нельзя произвольно *вставлять/удалять/переделывать* во времени выполнения.

Наиболее близким к вашей задаче альтернативным решением является реализация рефлексивного конструктора, принимающего два массива: один с названиями полей, другой - с соотвествующими значениями для инициализации.

```
...
public SomeClass (String[] fields, Object[] valuesForInit) {
    //Получаем класс и поля
    Class clazz = SomeClass.class;
    Field[] classFields = clazz.getFields();
    //Перебираем список всех полей и список нужных для инициализации
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length(); i++) {
        for (Field classField : classFields) {
            //Если поле нужно инициализировать и значение соответствует типу поля...
            if (field[i] == classField.getName() && valuesForInit[i] instanceof classField.getType()) {
                 //...инициализируем как нужно
                 //Тут вы как-нибудь сами
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Однако учтите - обычная рефлексия ужасно бьет по производительности. Если для вас это критично, ищите способы ускорения ([например](https://habrahabr.ru/post/69552/)) или другие решения.