# JAVA Можно ли создать переменную класа из массива String?

Tags: java

Можно ли в классе создать новые переменные из массива String? так, чтобы я мог к ним обратиться?
Например, я получаю из БД список всех столбцов. И хочу создать такое-же кол-во переменных с таким же название в теле класса, возможно ли это?

Comment: Объясните ваш вопрос, вы хотите создать переменные _динамически_?  Добавить переменные в рантайме, после того, как класс был создан и скомпилирован?

Comment: @NowhereMan именно так

Comment: А что вы дальше хотите делать с этими переменными? Они нужны вам для сериализации, отображения где-то или вы хотите еще сгенерировать какую-то логику работающую с ними? Если да, то какую?

Comment: @VyacheslavBenedichuk нужны для отображения, и арифметических действий. Ну я уже так понял, мне проще всего это делать через коллекции.

Comment: Да, проще и правильнее будет сделать это через коллекции, например, завести список названий столбцов и мапу/словарь с ключом-названием столбца и неким значением (или списком значений).

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Динамическое создание конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729736/), см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729835/386633) от Barmaley

Comment: @NowhereMan да, так и поступил. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в решении вашей проблемы вам поможет такой паттерн проектирования как Builder: https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/552412/